# Tracking the final variable value in for loops when code is executed

Tags: java, variables, for-loop

I know that the answer is 9, but when I try to work this out on paper, I keep getting that the answer is 6. I need to know what is happening with the code runs. Especially since in the beginning, the second for loop is false because x isn't less than y.

What value is printed when the above code is executed?

```
int w = 0;
for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++)
{
    w = y - 1;
    for (int x = 1; x < y; x++)
    {
        w = w + x;
    }
}
System.out.println(w);
```

Comment: What did you get when you executed it? Have you tried stepping through the code line by line to see what gets executed? It might also help for you to explain how you are getting 6 and how you think the program would get `9`?

Comment: When the compiler runs the code, the result is 9. However, when I tried going through it on paper, I end up getting 6. I don't quite understand what steps are being taken by the compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only loop that matters is the last one since the first part of the loop sets `w` without any care about it's previous value: `y = 4`.

So `w = 3`.

Then a loop that adds 1 2 and 3 to w.

- w = 3 + 1 -> w=4
- w = 4 + 2 -> w = 6
- w = 6 + 3 -> w = 9

Comment: Thanks! that helps a lot!